# Django make query dynamically for filter

Tags: python, django

this code works well

```
from django.db.models import Q
filtered = Article.objects.filter(Q(authers__id=2) | Q(issues__id=1) | Q(issues__id=3) )
```

However now I have list like this below, and want to make filter dynamically.

```
ids = [1,2,3]
for id in ids:
    eachQ = Q(authers__id=isId)
#then......
```

how can I make query ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying same field for different values(or condition) you can use __in key.

```
 possibilities = [1,2,3]
 Article.objects.filter(field__in=posibilities)
```

Also for dynamic queries you can pass **kwargs to filter method:

```
query_key = 'your_field_name__in'
Article.objects.filter(**{query_key:[1,2,3]#your search value})
```

You can add your multiple model field into kwargs param:

```
query = {'field_1':value_1,'field_2':value_2,'field_3__contains':value_3}#for example
Article.objects.filter(**query)
```

Comment: I can use the first way, it helps me very simply!!! and thanks for alternative ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of values for just one field, it`s better to use ['in' filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut):

```
ids = [1,2,3]
articles = Article.objects.filter(authers__id__in=ids)
```

Otherwise, for creating 'OR' filter iteratively:

```
from django.db.models import Q

filters = Q()
ids = [1, 2, 3]

for pk in ids:
    filters |= Q(authers__id=pk)

articles = Article.objects.filter(filters)
```

This can be used for dynamic filtering by multiple model fields and values.